# Why I can not repair or update index in Nexus Repository Manager 3?

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus

I have established maven repository in our intranet by nexus repository manager 3, and network access from my maven repository server to extranet is ok. And then I executed 'rebuild index' for my proxy repository, it told me success but the repository is still empty(that is cannot find any components in components browser) .And I also tried 'publish maven indexes' and 'rebuild maven repository metadata',but it still didn't work,and the manager shows me 'insufficient trend data',I don't know why and I don't know how to solve this and update index for my maven repository.
[image: the result after I executed 'rebuild index']
[image: my proxy repository,it is empty and can't find any components,the same as the other three proxy components]

Comment: Just to verify, do you have content in your NXRM server?  It is a common misconception that the search/browse shows the remote repositories.  In fact, you need to have content in there to be shown in the current versions.